# Turning screen off kills tkinter thus kills my Python alarm clock. How to fix?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, helper

Here is the full code. I am a total beginner and a lot of the code is from online. Anything will be a great help.

Turning screen off kills tkinter thus kills my Python alarm clock. How to fix?

The bulk of text below is junk I came up so you don't have to read it:
It is made up with 3 parts: the clock GUI display, the buttons and the alarm settings, and the turn off/ turn on monitor function. The design goal is to learn python and to make a wakeup sunrise thing to emulate sunrise with your monitor or a projector. So when the alarm goes off, the projector turns on, and displays a full screen clock with increasingly brighter colors in the background. In hoping to make the wakeup process easier for those who need to wake up in the dark. I am sure there are better implementations of this (I built one with a Chromebook and an Arduino controlling IR to turn on projector, and an Arduino relay standalone in the past) but still, it is for learning.

```
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import datetime
import os

import ctypes
def ScreenOff():
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, 2)
def ScreenOn():
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, -1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
root.frame = Frame(root)
root.frame.pack(fill = "both")
label = Label(root, text= "Welcome", bg = "black", fg = "white", font=("Times", 50))
label.pack(side= "top", fill = "both", expand = 1)
root.title_font = tkfont.Font(family = "Times", size = 100, weight = "bold", slant = "italic")
root.title("Clock")

def tick():
    global wake
    current_time = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    label.config(text=current_time)
    label.after(200, tick)


    # alarm start

def SubmitButton():
  AlarmTime= entry1.get()
  Message1()
  #label2.config(text ="The Alarm will Ring at {} ".format(AlarmTime))  #delayed in execution
  CurrentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M")
  print("the alarm time is: {}".format(AlarmTime))
  #label2.config(text="")
  while AlarmTime != CurrentTime:
    #label2.config(text ="The Alarm will Ring at {} ".format(AlarmTime))
    CurrentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    time.sleep(1)
    ScreenOff()
  if AlarmTime == CurrentTime:
     ScreenOn()
     print("now Alarm Musing Playing")
     os.system("start alarm-music.mp3")
     label2.config(text = "Alarm music playing.....")
     messagebox.showinfo(title= 'Alarm Message', message= "{}".format(entry2.get()))
def Message1():
    AlarmTimeLable= entry1.get()
    label2.config(text="the Alarm time is Counting...")
    #label2.config(text= "the Alarm will ring at {}".format(AlarmTimeLable))
    messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Alarm clock', message = 'Alarm will Ring at {}'.format(AlarmTimeLable))     
frame1 = ttk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
frame1.config(height = 100, width = 100)

label1= ttk.Label(frame1,text = "Enter the Alarm time :")
label1.pack()


entry1 = ttk.Entry(frame1, width = 30)
entry1.pack()
entry1.insert(3,"example - 13:15")

labelAlarmMessage= ttk.Label(frame1, text="Alarm Message:")
labelAlarmMessage.pack()

entry2= ttk.Entry(frame1, width=30)
entry2.pack()

button1= ttk.Button(frame1, text= "submit", command=SubmitButton)
button1.pack()
#this Label2 will show the Last Alarm Time
label2= ttk.Label(frame1)
label2.pack()

    
#label2.config(text="hello")



tick()
root.mainloop()
```

For example, can I restart Tkinter? or have it not to crash? Or allow it to crash but have my alarm still working in the background?

Many thanks!

Comment: _"The bulk of text below is junk I came up so you don't have to read it"_ - if it's junk, don't post it.

Comment: @BryanOakley MAYB he did that cause, or else they will say ur post is mostly code error? not sure, just saying

Comment: @CoolCloud: that's not a valid reason. Those rules exist for a reason and shouldn't be circumvented with junk code or junk text.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this  command in terminal in windows to run program as a background process

```
pythonw ./name.py
```

You can also use windows task scheduler for running you program in background